# The meaning of these bolded words

Tags: word-meaning, roots

> It had been a rough day, so when I walked into the party I was very **chalant**, despite my efforts to appear **gruntled** and **consolate**. I was furling my wieldy umbrella . . . when I saw her. . . . She was a **descript** person. . . . Her hair was **kempt**, her clothing **shevelled**, and she
>   moved in a **gainly** way.

I have difficulty understanding this passage, especially the bolded words. I didn't find those words in my dictionary. Can someone help explain it?

The passage is excerpted from

“How I Met My Wife” by Jack Winter from The New Yorker, July 25, 1994.

Comment: I don't believe this is a dictionary reference question; most dictionaries lack some, most, or even all of these words (for good reason: they are not really part of English per se).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This passage is a really a joke.  It is deliberately using a linguistic process called [back-formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation) to create a new word from an existing one by stripping away an apparent negative [prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix).

Consider the first of your bolded words: **chalant**.  There is a standard English word, **nonchalant**, that [is defined as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonchalant) "having an air of easy unconcern or indifference."  However, native speakers know that [non-](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non-) is a common prefix of negation, so it's easy to imagine that there might exist a word, **chalant**, that means the opposite of **nonchalant** (that is, "having air of extreme concern"), even though no such word actually exists in English.  (In French, there are the verbs **chaloir** and **nonchaloir**, which have opposite meanings, but only **nonchaloir** was adapted into an English word.)

This is true for all of your bolded words: they are English words that had what looks like a negative prefix stripped away from them, which English-speakers would understand as meaning the opposite of the original word through the logic of *back-formation*.  However, in all cases, the "new" word either doesn't exist in English, or is extremely uncommon.  Note that *The New Yorker* is written for a fairly educated audience, who would presumably understand and appreciate a linguistic joke like this.

Here are all of those original real words, in the same order as in the passage you quote:

**nonchalant, disgruntled, disconsolate, nondescript, unkempt, disheveled, ungainly**

All of them look like they have one of the negative prefixes **non-**, **dis-**, or **un-**.

Comment: You skipped wieldy, which was not bolded but is another of these words.

Comment: I am plussed by your assistance.

Comment: Not all of these are backformations, some of them actually did exist in English at one point.  These are known as "lost positives".